# Is it possible to link c code with llvm bitcode?

Tags: llvm, jit

I have an llvm bitcode file containing some useful functions. I want to call it from c code. Is it possible to link this c code with llvm bitcode to generate an executable? 
Or I have to call the function through JIT.

Answer (score 2):

The LLVM bitcode has to be made executable to be called from C. You have at least two choices:

1. JIT compile the bitcode before you call it.
2. llc the bitcode and assemble/link the object file with your C object files.

   1. is probably easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer is yes, assuming you are not using some unmentioned runtime C language interpreter.  Typically the C has to be compiled to something, the llvm tools give you two choices bitcode and assembly language for a target processor.  The C can be turned into bitcode and you have all components in the same executable binary.  From there you can take all of these parts and take them to assembly language for a particular target.